# How to print two lists of different size side by side?

Tags: python, list, python-3.4

I have two lists of different length that I want to print side by side, separated by a tab. As an example:

```
a_list = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
b_list = ["f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n"]
```

I tried:

```
print('A-list:'+ '\t' + 'B-list:')
for i in range(len(b_list)):
    print(a_list[i] + '\t' + b_list[i])
```

I off course get an "out of range-trace" back because one list is shorter. I do *not* wish to use zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible solution. It doesn't matter if `a_list` is longer or shorter than `b_list`.

```
def get(lst, idx):
    try:
        return lst[idx]
    except:
        return " "

a_list = ['a','b','c','d','e'] 
b_list = ['f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n']

result = []

for i in range(min(len(a_list), len(b_list))):
    result.append(get(a_list, i))
    result.append(get(b_list, i))

for i in range(min(len(a_list), len(b_list)), max(len(a_list), len(b_list))):
    result.append(get(a_list, i))
    result.append(get(b_list, i))

print('\n'.join('\t'.join((result[i], result[i+1]))
                          for i in range(0, len(result), 2)))
```

This prints the expected output:

```
a   f
b   g
c   h
d   i
e   j
    k
    l
    m
    n
```

Answer (score 1):

your code is rasing `IndexError` because the length of `b_list` is   greater than the length of `a_list`, for this, you could use a `try except` statement:

```
for i in range(max(len(b_list), len(a_list))):
    try:
        print(f"{a_list[i]}\t", end="")
    except IndexError:
        print(f" \t", end="")
    try:
        print(f"{b_list[i]}\t")
    except IndexError:
        print(f" \t")
```

output:

```
a   f
b   g
c   h
d   i
e   j
    k
    l
    m
    n
```

---

Comment: Thanks, however I do not wish to use zip or other functions that require import

Comment: it fails in case that list_a is longer

Comment: "I have two list of different length" OP said. that is an example. what is the matter is that your code should be able to print two lists with different length side by side.

Comment: @mahyard  and? did you test the last version?

Comment: That's better. but actually I prefer to avoid using try-except. using them often will make your code less readable and hard to understand. but it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

without any extra loop:

```
list_a = ["A", "B", "C"]
list_b = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
len_a = len(list_a)
len_b = len(list_b)
i = 0
while True:
    if i < len_a:
        print(list_a[i], end="")
    if i < len_b:
        print("\t", list_b[i], end="")
    print()
    i += 1
    if i > max(len_a, len_a):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def iterate(a_list, b_list):
  # iterate through short list
  min_length = min(((len(a_list), len(b_list)))) 

  for i in range(min_length):
    print('{}\t{}'.format(a_list[i], b_list[i]))

  # print remaining items accordingly
  if i + 1 == len(a_list):
    for item in b_list[i+1:]:
      print('\t{}'.format(item))  
  else:
    for item in a_list[i+1:]:
      print(item)
```

I advise use the string method format which allows you to have elements of any kind in your lists.

Answer (score 0):

In all solutions, the trick is to go through the longest list and use an empty space for missing entries in the shorter list.

For example:

```
a_list = ['a','b','c','d','e'] 
b_list = ['f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n']

for i in range(max(len(a_list),len(b_list))):
    a = a_list[i:i+1] or [""]
    b = b_list[i:i+1] or [""]
    print(a[0]+"\t"+b[0])
```

If you're not concerned with memory usage, you could also pad the lists with blanks in order to have a simpler printing process that assumes lists of same sizes:

```
padding  = len(b_list)-len(a_list)
a_padded = a_list + [""]*padding
b_padded = b_list + [""]*-padding
for i in range(len(a_padded)):
    print(a_padded[i]+"\t"+b_padded[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
test1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
test2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
test3 = [1, 2]

while test or test2 or test3:
    print(test.pop() if test else '',\
          test2.pop() if test2 else '',\
          test3.pop()if test3 else '')
```

Comment: You should also add some explanation of this.